The new question wizard is flickering when writing text
When writing a new question on ask wizard (don't forgt the check the "The Ask Wizard" at top of page), I found a disturbing issue.
When typing on 2 main boxes ("What are the details?" and "What did you tried?"), it's flickering for each char. It seems it's removing the content of the preview before make it again, instead of just replacing the old one by new one.
I'm on Chrome, version 127.0.6533.73.
Can you remove the flicker behavior?
Note: No, it's not a duplicate of MSO inline answer editor is doing rapid layout shift as I edit the body input. why? as I'm talking about the question wizard in SO (not answer on MSO)

MSO inline answer editor is doing rapid layout shift as I edit the body input. why?

Oh, I didn't see it, but it's not about the same part. This post is talking about answer on MSO, I'm talking about question on SO

The Wizard uses the same editor as MSO does. The Stacks editor (fortunately) isn't used elsewhere in public tooling on main. It's the same editor that's the problem, so where it's placed is irrelevant
